# ExceptionInInitializerError in android studion while running a github project

Tags: java, android, exception

I am running a project from github, but when i try to run the application on device it crashes. And the logcat is showing

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.gamestudio24.cityescape.android, PID: 29666
                                                                                 java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
                                                                                     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1090)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2327)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
                                                                                  Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load shared library 'gdx' for target: Linux, 32-bit
                                                                                     at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SharedLibraryLoader.load(SharedLibraryLoader.java:115)
                                                                                     at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxNativesLoader.load(GdxNativesLoader.java:34)
                                                                                     at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication.<clinit>(AndroidApplication.java:59)
                                                                                     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method) 
                                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1090) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2327) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) 
                                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.gamestudio24.cityescape.android-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.gamestudio24.cityescape.android-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libgdx.so"
                                                                                     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:367)
                                                                                     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1076)
                                                                                     at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SharedLibraryLoader.load(SharedLibraryLoader.java:111)
                                                                                     at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxNativesLoader.load(GdxNativesLoader.java:34) 
                                                                                     at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication.<clinit>(AndroidApplication.java:59) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method) 
                                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1090) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2327) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
```

plz suggest me how to resolve this error